# How to convert string to integer - weird format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a field named: `pa_value` which keeps `varchar` records
Now this field contains records like:

```
 - 0.5582%
 - 0.6985%
 - -0.1589%
 - 0.9856%
 - -0.6589%
```

I'm getting these results using the following code:

```
CAST (replace (p7.pa_value ,'%','') AS float (3,0)) as TotalMargin
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove everything and leave just 2 characters(or 3 if there is a -(minus) infront of the string).
It should be looking like this:

```
 - 55
 - 69
 - -15
 - 98
 - -65
```

I tried to cast it as a `float` and then to convert it to `integer`. I also tried the `floor` command, which is not for my case, without any success. I believe that there is no way to do this.

Comment: What can you say about the number of decimal places? Is this constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST((columnName * 100) as INTEGER) NewValue
FROM TableName;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c6ac/1)

Comment: Here is what I got: `Syntax error converting the varchar value '-0.0063' to a column of data type int.` :(

Comment: @Slim [Here, try it again (*added CAST*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/116a5/3) Hope it worked now. :D

Comment: Do you have NLS settings which expect a comma instead of a period? Then you can use to_number with an explict format model instead.

Comment: My case is kinda specific as the content also contains `%` in it. Here is what i tried without success `CAST((CAST(replace (p7.pa_value ,'%','') AS NUMERIC(10,6)) * 100) as INTEGER) NewValue,`

Comment: @Slim where is the percent located? can you post here some records? :D so i can modify the query

Comment: Hey it worked! Huge thanks!!! I lost about 3 hours looking for a solution!Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select cast(substring(col,0,charindex('.',col)+3) as float)*100 
from table1
```

## [SQl fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3581/6)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  CAST( CASE WHEN LEFT(VALUE, 1) = '-' THEN '-' ELSE '' END 
  + SUBSTRING(
        Value, 
        CASE WHEN LEFT(VALUE, 1) = '-' THEN 4 ELSE 3 END,
        2)
  AS INT) AS TotalMargin
FROM TableName
```

[**Fiddle-Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23d50/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE [SomeTable] 
SET p7.pa_value = 
    (CASE 
         WHEN LEN(LTRIM(p7.pa_value)) > 8 
            THEN  CAST(RIGHT(p7.pa_value, LEN(p7.pa_value) - 2) AS NUMERIC(10, 2))
         ELSE CAST(LTRIM(p7.pa_value) AS NUMERIC(10, 2))
     END);
GO
```

This checks whether the string has the leading unwanted '-' and deals with each case accordingly.

I hope this helps.