# Can't cut and convert a string - weird format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This question is almost the same with one of my previous questions, which can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376223/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-weird-format)

I have a field named: `pa_value` which keeps `varchar` records
Now this field contains records like:

```
 0,5582
 0,6985
 -0,1589
 0,9856
 -0,6589
```

I'm getting these results using the following code:

```
CAST (replace (p7.pa_value ,'%','') AS float (3,0)) as TotalMargin
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove everything and leave just 5 characters(or 6 if there is a -(minus) infront of the string).
It should be looking like this:

```
 55.82
 69.85
 -15.89
 98.56
 -65.89
```

I tried to cast it as a `float` and then to convert it to `integer`. I also tried the `floor` command, which is not for my case, without any success. I'm always getting a syntax error message. I believe that there is no way to do this

Comment: Couldn't you use the [same suggestion as before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376223/how-to-convert-string-to-integer-weird-format/13376282#13376282) but without the cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p7.pa_value=CASE WHEN LEFT( p7.pa_value,1)='-' THEN '-' + 
           CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(float,substring(p7.pa_value,4,4))/100) ELSE 
           CONVERT(varchar(max),CONVERT(float,substring(p7.pa_value,3,4))/100)  END
FROM <table_name>
```

**What is being done ..**

- Check if starting character is '-'.
- If yes then extract string starting from position 4 else starting
  from position 3.
- The inner convert function converts string to float for division and
  the outer convert changes back the resultant value back to varchar
  type.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are always four digits after the comma, you could use this, though I don't believe it's perfect:

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(9,2), REPLACE(REPLACE(p7.pa_value, '%', ''), ',', '')) / 100
```